# Solr change query result

Tags: solr

I have next filds on my managet-schema

```
  <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
  <field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="url" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Also I use edismax with query fields with optional boost (qf=body^2 title^100) option.

I have many urls from different domains, for instance:

```
http://domain1.com/
http://domain1.com/aaa
http://domain1.com/aaa/bbb
http://domain1.com/aaa/bbb2
http://domain1.com/aaa/bbb3
http://domain2.com/
http://domain2.com/aaa
http://domain2.com/aaa/bbb
http://domain2.com/aaa/bbb2
http://domain2.com/aaa/bbb3
http://domain3.com/
http://domain3.com/aaa
http://domain3.com/aaa/bbb
http://domain3.com/aaa/bbb2
http://domain3.com/aaa/bbb3
```

The problem is when I search I get many similar result from one domain, and results from next domain start from 30-100 doc. How can get result from different domain on the top.

Comment: You'll have to separate the domain of the URL out into its own field, then use [Collapse and Expand](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html) to group your results on that field.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I can't find a good example, can you explain it in more detail.         >You'll have to separate the domain of the URL out into its own field  did you mean that I have to create a new field and set there only domain name like: http://domain1.com, http://domain2.com etc...?  When I use {!collapse field=url} in my query, nothing is changed.

Comment: I read further more and try it out but the issue is that each url very similar but not same. Even if I use group=true&group.field=url I get groups with numFound=1. Any other suggestions? Can we use regexp somehow?

Comment: Yes, you have to extract the domain part of the URL and index into a new field. You can't use the `url` field for grouping, since it's already unique values and won't give you anything useful. I also recommend using a `string` field for the domain field, since you do not want any processing or tokenization to take place on that field.

Comment: @MatsLindh dude, add it as an answer, I'll check it as positive))) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to separate the domain name of the URL into its own field. You can't use the `url` field since it only contains unique values already, and the field you use for grouping should also be a `string` field (i.e. it won't get split into multiple tokens).

You can then use the [Collapse & Expand support](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/collapse-and-expand-results.html) to collapse the result set based on domain:

```
q=...&fq={!collapse field=domain}&expand=true
```